# AWS Randomize data for large tables

Tags: random, sql-update, amazon-redshift

I have a table in redshift with values over 1.8 billion i am trying to randomize that data.

Here is the table values attributes

```
id    bigint,
customer_internal_id    bigint,
customer_id    VARCHAR(256) Not NULL,
customer_name    VARCHAR(256) Not NULL,
customer_type_id    bigint,
start_date    date,
end_date    date,
request_id    bigint,
entered    VARCHAR(256) not NULL,
superseded    VARCHAR(256) not NULL,
customer_latitude    double precision,
customer_longitude    double precision,
zip_internal_id    bigint
```

How can i achieve this as i tried to look for more of an option but there is no enough documentation available.

Here is the expected output.

[image]

i have some code written for PostgresSQL

```
with result as (
  select id, customer_id, customer_name,
         lead(customer_id) over w as first_1,
         lag(customer_name) over w as first_2
  from master.customer_temp_df
  window w as (order by random())
)
update master.customer_temp_df
  set customer_id = coalesce(first_1, first_2),customer_name = coalesce(first_2, first_1)
from result 
where master.customer_temp_df.id = result.id;
```

but this doesnt work in redshift and i am looking for something like this.
The final goal is to randomize entire table.

Comment: Randomize in what way? Can you give an example of your existing data and your resulting randomized data?

Comment: i have added in question now.

Comment: It looks like you're taking `customer_internal_id` and swapping it with `customer_type_id`. Surely this will violate referential integrity to just swap values between columns. What is the purpose of this randomization?

Comment: trying to analyze performance of my aws cluster, this is for testing i have generated so even though there is no referential integrity between customer_internal_id and customer_type_id its fine.

Comment: In that case, could you avoid all this swapping and just update each row with random values? What performance are you trying to test?

Comment: i want to keep some varchar values as it is and doesn't want to change with the numbers generated by random function.  Mostly want to check select query performance for single record join or subquery.

Comment: How will you test join performance without referential integrity? What does retaining specific varchar values matter for a join performance check?

Comment: i will be joining on id only.